# Simple logging of expressions and functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, logging

Is there a simple logging like this in Kotlin?
Or something similar only for expressions, not for functions.

```
@Log
fun multi(param1: Int, param2: Int) = param1 * param2
```

Call:

```
val res = multi(20, 30)
```

Output:

```
"multy(20, 30) = 20 * 30 = 600"
```

Comment: No there isn't. You can probably do this by writing your own annotation processor though.